# tensorflow performance confusion

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow for a non-neural-net project (interacting particles), and have two version of the potential function. Here is version 1:

```
def coulomb(t, fudge = tf.constant(1000000.0)):
  howmany = t.shape[0]
  x = t[:, 0:1]
  y = t[:, 1:2]
  z = t[:, 2:3]

  dx = tf.transpose(x) - x
  dy = tf.transpose(y) - y
  dz = tf.transpose(z) - z
  rmat = tf.sqrt(dx **2  + dy **2 + dz **2)
  rmat = tf.linalg.set_diag(tf.cast(rmat, tf.float32), fudge * tf.ones(howmany))

  inv = 1.0/rmat

  PE = tf.reduce_sum(inv)/2

  return PE
```

I thought that breaking out individual `x, y, z` was kind of ugly, and probably slow, so here is a slicker version 2:

```
def coulomb2(t, fudge = tf.constant(1000000.0)):
  howmany = t.shape[0]

  tt = tf.expand_dims(t, 1)
  difft = tf.transpose(tt, perm=(1, 0, 2)) - tt
  rmat = tf.norm(difft, axis=2)
  rmat = tf.linalg.set_diag(tf.cast(rmat, tf.float32), fudge * tf.ones(howmany))

  inv = 1.0/rmat

  PE = tf.reduce_sum(inv)/2

  return PE
```

The good news is that the two versions return exactly the same results. The bad news is that the slick version is much, much slower (almost a factor of two). Does anyone understand why this would be, or what the "canonical" way to write such code is?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really good enough for an answer, but I also don't have enough cred to comment...so I'd suggest maybe not using tf.norm, and instead compute the norm by hand like you did in the first Coulomb potential function.

(I know this isn't about numpy, but you can also compare np.linalg.norm against `math.sqrt(np.sum(x*x))`...and on my systems I see the former is significantly slower. Maybe both np and tf compute the norm using singular values?)

Comment: Thanks! I just took a look at the numpy sources and they do use svd. I had not even realized this was a thing :)

Comment: @IgorRivin I think it's like they want to allow for people to plug in matrices and then output a 2-norm/greatest singular value. Maybe what you want is something like this:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_euclidean_norm

...would be interesting to hear if it helps accelerate the tensorflow code at all

Comment: I tried, and yes, it does help quite a bit, but the timing is still worse than the "stupid" method (this time by only 5-10%).  I wonder what is taking the time. I would be stunned if "reduce_euclidean_norm" did something different from the hand computation (and you might think it would do it faster). Is the 3D tensor transpose the issue? That would also be shocking.

Comment: It very well could be...I think I recall seeing once that tf.transpose might need to change the layout of how the bloody tensor is stored in memory - I could be wrong though, will try to find a reference on this